# How to include third party library in hadoop when Using amazon elastic mapreduce service

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have to do some data-mining tasks using third party library called weka. But I am not sure how to include the required jar file in amazon elastic mapreduce service.

Does anybody have experience in dealing with this case?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to put your dependencies in your jar file with the mappers and reducers.
If your building with Maven I recommend to use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugin to package a single jar with all dependencies.